# How to allow untrusted providers in IIS7?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, iis, iis-7, configuration

I need to allow untrusted providers in IIS7. I think that this is accomplished by editing the trustedProviders section of Administrator.config, but I don't know exactly how to do this.

I want to do this so that I can manage users directly from IIS7's gui.

Is it a text file? Where is it? If I can't edit it directly, how do I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry about that - to allow untrusted providers:

- edit c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\config\administration.config
- edit the trustedProviders node to have the new key/value: allowUntrustedProviders="true". It should look like this:

  trustedProviders allowUntrustedProviders="true"
- save the file
- iisreset

I believe you will get warning messages in IIS Manager when you try to edit roles/users, but it should work. Also, Microsoft recommends against using untrusted providers due to security concerns.

Comment: That file doesn't exist on my server.

Comment: Do you have any files in that folder? There should be 3 config files - administration.config, applicationHost.config and redirection.config.

Comment: Just thought of another possibility - are you using Shared Configuration? This would put the administration.config file somewhere else.

Comment: I must be losing it, because I browsed to that directory again and the files were there. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Ronnie Overby These files do **not** show in Total Commander, but I can access them if I open `c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\config` with Windows Explorer.

Answer (score 1):

First thing you need to do is make sure the assembly for your provider is signed, strongly-named and stored in the GAC. Get the Culture, Version and Public Key Token values for your assembly out of the GAC

Edit the file:
c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\config\administration.config

Find the trustedProviders section, and add a new line for your provider as follows:

```
add type="MyCompany.CustomProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c14f5f7f11d61b3a
```

(where the type name, version, culture and publickeytoken are what you pulled out of the GAC)

Save the file

iisreset

In the web.config file for your site, make sure that the provider is referenced using the fully qualified assembly type name, and you should be good to go.

Comment: You're not answering my question. Instead of going to all the trouble of compiling a separate assembly, and doing all of that stuff you said, I just want to allow untrusted providers. I know it can be done because there is an attribute called allowUntrustedProviders (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.web.management.server.managementadministrationconfiguration.allowuntrustedproviders.aspx). That's what I want to do. Thanks, anyway.